# Understand and reproduce withdrawn publication method - Blastp - covid19

Tags: coronavirus, blast

I try to reproduce the method of [this withdrawn paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.01.30.927871v1.full.pdf). I know this paper has been debunked and withdrawn. I am curious to understand the details of the method used on it. I am a programmer and I don't work on the field of Biology.

I have some questions about "The identified amino acid and nucleotide sequence" with 
[MultAlign](http://multalin.toulouse.inra.fr/multalin/) software: [image: Image from the paper]

I have trouble to understand how those supposed "inserts" were selected:

- "Insert 1": The selection is where there are dashes and dots on the second and third lines because the sequence is not present in SARS-GZ02
- "Insert 2": The beginning of the "insert" start with these dash and dots but **why is it stopped at 155** ?
- "Insert 3": The end at 261 is at a dash for the second line but **why does it starts at 256?**
- "Insert 4": **why these start and end of selection?**

Later on the paper they used these selected regions with [Blast](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) and on the "motif alignement" column these letters are used which are a little different:

- "Insert 1": TNGTKR (first letter "G" removed)
- "Insert 2": HKNNKS ("YY" removed)
- "Insert 3": RSYL-TPGDSSSG (4 letters at 250 added)
- "Insert 4": QTNS-PRRA

[image: motifs]

**Why are some different from the selection ?**

Even for the first "insert", I can't find those alignement with [Blast](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) using for example GTNGTKR or TNGTKR. **If someone could indicate me the good parameters in [Blast](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) to find these alignements** it would be awesome.

Sorry if it sounds too ingenuous, thank you for your time reading all this.